# TimeOut Session usando StateServer

Tags: c#, session

Tenho uma aplicação em `cluster` que uso as `Session`, para não dar problema coloquei outra maquina para servir de `Session Server` e configurei o `web.config` da seguinte forma:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=[IP]:42424" stateNetworkTimeout="3600" timeout="1440" />
```

Deixei o timeout em 1440 min para deixar a sessão ativa por 1 dia, mas existem casos que o usuário entra no sistema e depois de min ele perde a sessão, o `TimeOut` do `SessionState` não serviria justamente para não acontecer isso? e como posso detectar o que está fazendo as sessões serem perdidas?

Comment: Depende de como o usuário está saindo e voltando. A sessão é identificada por um cookie no browser do cliente, se ele está utilizando diferentes navegadores ou se o cookie está sendo perdido, a sessão não será identificada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há várias possibilidades, vou elencar as mais comuns:

1. Seu servidor (StateServer) está sendo reiniciado e está guardando as sessões na memória
2. Seu banco de dados que guarda as sessões está sendo apagado (alguém limpa ele) com alguma frequencia
3. O usuário está usando o modo incógnito (anônimo) de navegação dos browsers
4. O usuário está limpando os cookies e sessões manualmente ou o browser está configurado para fazer isso quando fechar
5. O usuário está trocando de browser (a sessão não é mantida entre browsers)
6. Em algum ponto de seu código você pode ter um `Session.Abandon()` ou `lougout`

No `global.asax` você pode colocar manipuladores de erros para pegar as exceções que não estão sendo tratadas e pegar algum erro que eventualmente não estejam sendo reportadas ou detectadas.

---

### Complementação

A sessão pode estar configurada diferente na parte de autenticação e na parte do HTTP, dentro de seu `web.config`. Vou explicar. Veja o seguinte exemplo de `web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="20" mode="SQLServer" cookieless="false" sqlConnectionString="data source=servidor\SQL2012;user id=user_aspstate;password=aspstate"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="MeuAuth" loginUrl="Login.aspx" path="/" timeout="10000" protection="All"/>
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Perceba que o timeout da autenticação é de 10.000 minutos! O valor default dessa propriedade é de 30 minutos. Já o sessionState está configurado com um timeout de 20 minutos, que já é o valor default que o .NET coloca para esta propriedade. Caso o forms tenha um timeout menor do que o sessionState ele vai acontecer antes. E pode ser que seu `web.config` esteja com esse probleminha de valores diferentes.

Comment: No código eu tenho um session.abadon() mesmo mas ele só mata a sessão daquele usuário né?

Comment: @user3258 sim, só daquele usuário, mas tem de ver em que momento ele é chamado. Está dentro de algo que é chamado automáticamente? Num link que o usuário clica? No global.asax? Tenta colocar um breakpoint em todos os `Session.Abandon()` e vê se não está caindo lá.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na comlementação que eu coloquei. Lembrei desse detalhe agora.